# I am trying to create a code polisher program in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create the function `delete_comments()`. The `read_file()` and `main` functions are given.

> Implement function `char *delete_comments(char *input)` that removes C comments from program stored at input. input variable points to dynamically allocated memory. The function returns pointer to the polished program. You may allocate a new memory block for the output, or modify the content directly in the input buffer.
>
> You’ll need to process two types of comments:
>
> Traditional block comments delimited by `/*` and `*/`. These comments may span multiple lines. You should remove only characters starting from `/*` and ending to `*/` and for example leave any following newlines untouched.
>
> Line comments starting with `//` until the newline character. In this case, newline character must also be removed.
>
> The function calling `delete_comments()` only handles return pointer from `delete_comments()`. It does not allocate memory for any pointers. One way to implement `delete_comments()` function is to allocate memory for destination string. However, if new memory is allocated then the original memory in input must be released after use.

I'm having trouble understanding why my current approach is wrong or what is the specific problem that I'm getting weird output. I'm approaching the problem by trying to create a new array where to copy the input string with the new rules.

```c
#include "source.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Remove C comments from the program stored in memory block <input>.
 * Returns pointer to code after removal of comments.
 * Calling code is responsible of freeing only the memory block returned by
 * the function.
 */
char *delete_comments(char *input)
{
    input = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof (char));
    char *secondarray = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof (char));

    int x, y = 0;

    for (x = 0, y = 0; input[x] != '\0'; x++) {
        if ((input[x] == '/') && (input[x + 1] == '*')) {
            int i = 0;
            while ((input[x + i] != '*') && (input[x + i + 1] != '/')) {
                y++;
                i++;
            }
        }

        else if ((input[x] == '/') && (input[x + 1] == '/')) {
            int j = 0;
            while (input[x + j] != '\n') {
                y++;
                j++;
            }
        }

        else  {
            secondarray[x] = input[y];
            y++;
        }
    }

    return secondarray;
}


/* Read given file <filename> to dynamically allocated memory.
 * Return pointer to the allocated memory with file content, or
 * NULL on errors.
 */
char *read_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!f)
        return NULL;
    
    char *buf = NULL;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    const unsigned int ReadBlock = 100;
    unsigned int n;
    do {
        buf = realloc(buf, count + ReadBlock + 1);
        n = fread(buf + count, 1, ReadBlock, f);
        count += n;
    } while (n == ReadBlock);
    
    buf[count] = 0;
    
    return buf;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *code = read_file("testfile.c");
    if (!code) {
        printf("No code read");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("-- Original:\n");
    fputs(code, stdout);

    code = delete_comments(code);
    printf("-- Comments removed:\n");
    fputs(code, stdout);
   
    free(code);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider writing some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which would transform some [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html), perhaps deleting what you want to remove? Or use [GNU flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to *generate* the C code you want. Please provide some [mre] in your question (we have no idea about what `source.h` contains) !!

Comment: VTC as typo. Your function starts with `char *delete_comments(char *input) { input = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char)); ...` So you receive a pointer to a character array, and you immediately erase it, meaning that you can no longer access the string you received as a parameter. That is enough for the function to have any behaviour except the expected one...

Comment: Read also wikipage on [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)s

Comment: This needs to be more complex because "comments" inside string literals are not comments (e.g. `char * foo = "/* not a comment */" /* a comment */`) .

Comment: Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) or of [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  GIMPLE will not preserve preprocessing directives, if that is a requirement.

Comment: ... and it is almost certainly a requirement for a "code polisher"; something that polishes source code isn't useful if it strips preprocessing directives. (It can conceivably be useful if it strips comments, depending on their quality.)

Answer (score 2):

Your program has fundamental issues.

1. It fails to tokenize the input. Comment start sequences can occur inside string literals, in which case they do not denote comments:  `"/* not a comment"`.
2. You have some basic bugs:

   ```
    if ((input[x] == '/') && (input[x + 1] == '*')) {
        int i = 0;
        while ((input[x + i] != '*') && (input[x + i + 1] != '/')) {
            y++;
            i++;
        }
    }
   ```

   Here, when we enter the loop, with `i = 0`, `input + x` is still pointing to the opening `/`. We did not skip over the opening `*` and are already looking for a closing `*`. This means that the sequence `/*/` will be recognized as a complete comment, which it isn't.

   This loop's also assumes that every `/*` comment is properly closed. It's not checking for the null character which can terminate the input, so if the comment is not closed, it will march beyond the end of the buffer.
3. C has line continuations. In ISO C translation stage 2, all backlash-newline sequences are deleted, converting one or more physical lines into logical lines. What that means is that a `//` comment can span multiple physical lines:

   ```
    // this is an \
    extended comment
   ```

   You can see, by the way, that StackOverflow's automatic language detector for syntax highlighting is getting this right!

   Line continuations are independent of tokenization, which doesn't happen until translation stage 3. Which means:

   ```
    /\
    /\
    this is an extended \
    comment
   ```

   That one has defeated StackOverflow's syntax highlighting.
   Furthermore, a line continuation can happen in any token, possibly multiple times:

   ```
    "\
    this is a string literal\
    "
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has several problems:

#### The worst issue

As the first instruction in `delete_comments()` you overwrite `input` with a new pointer returned by `malloc()`, which points to memory of random contents.

In consequence the address to the real input is lost.

Oh, and please check the returned value, if you call `malloc()`.

#### Failing to increment the scanned position in comments correctly

You are scanning the input by the index `x`, but if you detect a comment, you don't change it.

You are actually advancing `y` but this is only used for the copying.

Think about lines like these:

```c
    int x; /* some /* weird /* comment */
    ///////////////////////////////
    for (;;) { }
```

#### Ignoring character and string literals

Your solution should take character and string literals into account.

For example:

```c
    int c_plus_plus_comment_start = '//'; /* multi character constant */
    const char* c_comment_start = "/*";
```

*Note: There are more. Learn to use a debugger, or at least insert lots of `printf()`s in "interesting" places.*

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make this work 100% correctly, you need to parse the input.  By "parse" I mean a more formal, rigorous detection routine that understands what it is reading, in the context it is reading it.

For example, there are many times where this code could be defeated.

printf("the answer is %d // %d\n", a, b);

would likely trip your `//` detection and strip the end of the `printf`.

There are two general approaches to the problem above:

1. Find every corner case where comment-like characters could be used, and write conditional statements to avoid them before stripping.
2. Fully parse the language, so you will know if you are within a string or some other context that's wrapping comment like characters, or if you are in the top level context where the characters really mean "this is a comment"

To learn about parsing, I generally recommend "The Dragon Book" but it is a hard read, unless you have studied a bit of *Discrete Mathematics*.  It covers a lot of different parsing techniques, and in doing so it doesn't have many pages left for examples.  This means that it's the kind of book where you have to read, think, and then program a mini-example.  If you follow that path, there is no input you can't tackle.

If you are pragmatic in your solution, and it is not about learning parsing, but about stripping comments, I recommend that you find a well constructed parser for C, and then learn how to walk the Abstract Syntax Tree in an Emitter, which fails to emit the comments.

There are some projects that do this already; but, I don't know if they have the right structure for easy modification.  `lint` comes to mind, as well as other "pretty-printers"  GCC certainly has the parsing code in there, but I've heard that GCC's Abstract Syntax Tree isn't easy to learn.